# Sort an ArrayList by primitive boolean type

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist, java-collections-api

I want to sort my `ArrayList` using a boolean type. Basically i want to show entries with `true` first. Here is my code below:

**Abc.java**

```
public class Abc {
 int id;
 bool isClickable;

 Abc(int i, boolean isCl){
    this.id = i;
    this.isClickable = iCl;
 }
 }
```

**Main.java**

```
List<Abc> abc = new ArrayList<Abc>();

//add entries here

//now sort them
Collections.sort(abc, new Comparator<Abc>(){
        @Override
        public int compare(Abc abc1, Abc abc2){

            boolean b1 = abc1.isClickable;
            boolean b2 = abc2.isClickable;

            if (b1 == !b2){
                return 1;
            }
            if (!b1 == b2){
                return -1;
            }
            return 0;
        }
    });
```

Order before sorting:
     true 
     true 
     true 
     false 
     false 
     false 
     false 
     true 
     false 
     false

Order after sorting:
false 
 false 
 true 
 true 
 true 
 true 
 false 
 false 
 false 
 false

Comment: if they are `==` return 0. If they are `!=`, then use 1 or -1 based on whether the first one is true or false.

Comment: Your second `if` condition will never evaluate to `true`.  It is synonymous with the first one.

Comment: you need to define the sort you need, is it involved with the id?

Answer (score 56):

Another way to go is:

```
Collections.sort(abc, new Comparator<Abc>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Abc abc1, Abc abc2) {
            return Boolean.compare(abc2.isClickable,abc1.isClickable);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Just a comment on this: Boolean.compare requires API level 19 if your app supports lower levels you should use the other replies, otherwise this is good for API 19 and above.

Comment: For descending order, I'd probably go for `-Boolean.compare(abc1.isClickable,abc2.isClickable)` instead. Switching the order of abc1 and abc2 seems really easy to miss, leading one to think the method is just sorting in ascending order.

Comment: with Java 8: `Collections.sort(abc, (object1, object2) -> Boolean.compare(object1.isClickable, object2.isClickable));` will do the trick. False will be at the top of the list. I would also suggest that use LinkedList instead of ArrayList to maintain order after sorting

Comment: did you run into a nullPointerException. How did you make use of Comparator.nullsLast or nullsFirst?

Answer (score 29):

why dont use something like this, its easier and java 8

```
listOfABCElements = {true, false, false, true, true};
listOfABCElements.stream().sorted(Comparator.comparing(Abc::isClickable,Comparator.reverseOrder()).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

output: true,true,true,false,false

reverseOrder is for order first true and after false, in other case falses goes first

```
listOfABCElements.stream().sorted(Comparator.comparing(Abc::isClickable).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

output: false,false,true,true,true

Answer (score 25):

In this case one of the easiest solutions is to convert booleans to integers, where `false` is `0` and `true` is `1`. Then return the difference of the second one and the first one.

So:

```
        int b1 = abc1.isClickable ? 1 : 0;
        int b2 = abc2.isClickable ? 1 : 0;

        return b2 - b1
```

should do it.

Answer (score 15):

Using Kotlin you can do smth like this:

```
listOfABCElements.sortBy { it.isClickable }
```

output: false,false,true,true,true

in reverse order:

```
listOfABCElements.sortByDescending { it.isClickable }
```

output: true,true,true,false,false

Comment: This is not correct:

```listOfABCElments.sortBy { it.isClickable }```

output will be: false,false,true,true,true

while the reverse order will be:

`listOfABCElements.sortByDescending { it.isClickable }`

output will be: true,true,true,false,false

Answer (score 10):

I want the items with `true` value to appear first. My solution would be:

```
Collections.sort(m_mall, new Comparator<Mall>(){

        @Override
        public int compare(Mall mall1, Mall mall2){

            boolean b1 = mall1.isClickable;
            boolean b2 = mall2.isClickable;

            return (b1 != b2) ? (b1) ? -1 : 1 : 0;
        }
    });
```

Comment: never do things like `if (someboolean == true)` it's a code smell and is equivalent to `if (someboolean)`

Comment: the second nested `if ` (`if (b1 == false) {`) could be replaced with just `return 1;`.

Comment: You're both right and the body of the outer `if` can be replaced with `return b1 ? -1 : 1;` :D

Comment: the whole if logic can be replaced with something like `return (b1 != b2) ? (b1) ? -1 : 1 : 0;`

Comment: and sadly, now the readability of the code is very low with too much optimization

Answer (score 5):

A simple suggestion would be to use the object `Boolean` instead of boolean and use `Collections.sort`.

However, you must know that the `false` will be before the `true` because true are represented as `1` and false as `0`. But then, you could just change your algorithm and access in reverse order.

**Edit** : As soulscheck stated, you could use `Collections.reverseOrder` to revert the ordering imposed by the Comparator.

Answer (score 5):

It is also possible that way.

```
myList.sort((a, b) -> Boolean.compare(a.isSn_Principal(), b.isSn_Principal()));
```

Answer (score 4):

Java 8:

```
 Collections.sort(abc, (abc1, abc2) ->
                  Boolean.compare(abc2.isClickable(), abc1.isClickable()));
```