# Collections Sort unexpected behaviour

Tags: java, sorting

Collections sort is not giving me the result I was expecting, or am I misreading the method?

List of Row objects is to be sorted:

```
public class Row {

    private int id;
    private boolean line;

    public Row(int id, boolean line) {
        this.id = id;
        this.line = line;
    }

    public boolean isLine() {
        return line;
    }

    @Override public String toString() {
        return "Row{" + "id=" + id + ", line=" + line + '}';
    }
}
```

Starting data:

```
[Row{id=0, line=true}, Row{id=1, line=false}, Row{id=2, line=true}, Row{id=3, line=false}]
```

Sorting code:

```
    Collections.sort(rows, new Comparator<Row>(){
        @Override public int compare(Row o1, Row o2) {
            if (!o1.isLine() && !o2.isLine()) return 0;
            if (o1.isLine()) {
                    return 1;
            } else {
                    return -1;
            }
        }
    });
```

Result:

```
[Row{id=1, line=false}, Row{id=3, line=false}, Row{id=0, line=true}, Row{id=2, line=true}]
```

I was under the impresion that all objects with `line=true` should be at the start of the list, not the end.

If I slightly change Comporator implementation:

```
    Collections.sort(rows, new Comparator<Row>(){
        @Override public int compare(Row o1, Row o2) {
            if (!o1.isLine() && !o2.isLine()) return 0;
            if (o1.isLine()) {
                return -1;
            } else {
                return 1;
            }
        }
    });
```

Result:

```
[Row{id=2, line=true}, Row{id=0, line=true}, Row{id=1, line=false}, Row{id=3, line=false}]
```

All of objects with `line=true` can be found at the start of the list now, but they have switched places (`id=0` should be first).

**Expected sort result:**

```
[Row{id=0, line=true}, Row{id=2, line=true}, Row{id=1, line=false}, Row{id=3, line=false}]
```

Comment: Your comparator should also take `id` into account .

Comment: If `compare(o1, o2)` returns 1, it means o1 is greater. The result of the first call is perfectly in line with that.

Comment: @Dukeling Does that mean that higher value objects (compare returns 1) are pushed to the end of the list?

Comment: The result is in ascending order (small to big).

Comment: Your first if-statement should be `if (o1.isLine() == o2.isLine())` - otherwise, if both are true, your sort will sometimes return 1 and sometimes return -1 (when it should return 0 all the time). But really you can just replace your entire method by `!Boolean.compare(o1.isLine(), o2.isLine())`.

Comment: @Dukeling that's a good point. Summarise all your comments in to the answer and I will accept it.

Comment: @CrazySabbath You're welcome to post my comments in an answer yourself if you feel it would be helpful to future visitors.

Comment: This might be a duplicate of [Sort an ArrayList by primitive boolean type](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28002342)

Comment: Sorting is from lowest to highest.

Answer (score 3):

> I was under the impresion that all objects with line=true should be at
>   the start of the list, not the end.

Not really as this code :

```
  if (o1.isLine()) {
       return 1;
  }
```

means that `o1` is superior to `o2`.
So object with `isLine=true` will happen to the end as default order is ascending.

> All of objects with line=true can be found at the start of the list
>   now, but they have switched places (id=0 should be first).

You never use the `id` in the comparator implementation.
It could never be considered.

To get :

> [Row{id=0, line=true}, Row{id=2, line=true}, Row{id=1, line=false},
>   Row{id=3, line=false}]

You should add a getter in `Row` to retrieve the `id`.
Then you should first sort by `line=true` and by `id` ASC.

```
 Collections.sort(rows, new Comparator<Row>(){
    @Override public int compare(Row o1, Row o2) {
        if (!o1.isLine() && !o2.isLine()) return 0;
        if (o1.isLine() && o2.isLine()) {
            return o1.getId() > o2.getId();
        }
        if (o1.isLine()) {
            return -1;
        } else {
            return 1;
        }
    }
 });
```

A more brief way to write that would be using Java 8 Comparator :

```
Comparator<Row> comparatorRow = Comparator.comparing(Row::isLine).reversed()
                                          .thenComparing(Row::getId);
```

---

As rows are already sorted by `id` and the sort is guaranteed to be stable: **equal elements will not be reordered as a result of the sort**,  you could compare only on `isLine` :

```
Comparator<Row> comparatorRow = Comparator.comparing(Row::isLine).reversed();
```

Comment: No I don't rely on that, first if statement ensures that. Why is this even upvoted?

Comment: @CrazySabbath That's strange - if both lines are false then we don't care about ids, but if both are true we do? A secondary sort criterion should be honoured if the primary one is equal.

Comment: laune you are correct, I summarised @Dukeling comments, which works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Summarising @Dukeling:

```
    Collections.sort(rows, new Comparator<Row>(){
        @Override public int compare(Row o1, Row o2) {
            return -Boolean.compare(o1.isLine(), o2.isLine());
        }
    });
```

This gives expected result.

Input:

```
[Row{id=0, line=true}, Row{id=1, line=false}, Row{id=2, line=true}, Row{id=3, line=false}]
```

Result:

```
[Row{id=0, line=true}, Row{id=2, line=true}, Row{id=1, line=false}, Row{id=3, line=false}]
```

Comment: The id sorting is not considered in your implementation. So the expected is fine but it's just chance.  Add more objects in your list and  id should not be sorted in ascending way.

Comment: @davidxxx Tried with 1000 objects, all Ids are in ascending order.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I suppose that id are already sorted in the list before invoking `sort()` and sort() implementation makes that the order is maintained as it processes in an iterative way. But it is not a solid way to define a comparator. The algorithm could change at runtime or in future JDK versions.

Comment: @davidxxx Collections.sort uses a stable sort algorithm, and that is guaranteed by the Javadoc.

Comment: @Klitos Kyriacou Have you a reference about it ?

Comment: @davidxxx yes, https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort-java.util.List- says "This sort is guaranteed to be stable: equal elements will not be reordered as a result of the sort."

Comment: @Klitos Kyriacou I didn't know that.Thanks a lot !

Comment: @davidxxx by the way, instead of `Collections.sort(rows, comparator)` it's simpler to write `rows.sort(comparator)`; however, unlike `Collections.sort`, the Javadoc for `List.sort` doesn't explicitly guarantee a stable sort although it mentions that the current implementation is indeed stable.

Answer (score 0):

Your comparision is not symmetric and hence broken. Use inverted comparision implemented in *Boolean* class (please note *minus* in start of lambda body):

```
Collections.sort(rows, (o1, o2) -> -Boolean.valueOf(o1.isLine()).compareTo(o2.isLine()));
```

Comment: I think you mean either `Boolean.compare(...)` or `Boolean.valueOf(...).compareTo(...)`